# (PHP) Button clicking counter on Cloning button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new to PHP.
Now I have a problem about how to count how many times I click on Cloning field button.

This is my codes so far.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
include('DBconnect.php');

mysql_query("USE onlinerecruitment");

$counter = 0;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM position WHERE Position_Recruit_Status = '1'");
?>

<form method="POST" action="confirm-weight-score-setup.php">
    <div id="main_wrap">

        Weight Score Set up 

        <br><br><font color="red">*Total Skill weight Must be equal to 10</font>

        <br><br>Position : &nbsp

        <SELECT name='position'>

            <?php
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                echo "<option value='" . $row["Position_ID"] . "'>" . $row["Position_Name"] . "</option>";
            }
            ?>

        </SELECT>

        <button onClick="history.back()";> Back </button> &nbsp
        <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Submit">

        <!-- + button -->   
        <div id="clone" >

            <br><br>Skill name <input type="text" name="skill_name[]"/>  &nbsp
            Skill weight (Not more than 10) <input type="number" name="skill_weight[]" min="0.0" max="10.0" step="0.1" value="0.0">

        </div>

        <!-- + button  -->
        <div style="float:right;">
            <input type ="button" value="+" name = "more" id="more" style="float:right;"> 

        </div>

</form>

</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#more").click(function () {
            $("#clone").clone().appendTo("#main_wrap");
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is button part that I want the counter to count how many times users click on this button

```
<!-- + button  -->
        <div style="float:right;">
            <input type ="button" value="+" name = "more" id="more" style="float:right;"> 

        </div>
```

I have no idea what I have to do, I tried to search this issue but found only `POST` button answer not "Button on click" so I don't know how to do it and where I have to place the codes.

Comment: I don't understand. Where do you want to keep count, and of what exactly? Can you make your question more general?

Comment: This looks like a JQuery problem rather than PHP. To start off, if you are cloning #clone you will end up with multiple elements with the same ID. Anyway, you have to count how many elements you have before cloning, if you have 10 don't clone.

Comment: @Ni. Ok, now I put the focus point on the button that I want to count after the main codes.

Comment: @user1655756 It is only 2 fields above and I retrieve those data into array.

Comment: If you want to count how many times someone clicks on the #more button why don't you keep an integer variable and add 1 every time someone clicks. If the variable is 10 and they click again you return false

Comment: @user1655756 Sounds good, but I don't know how to do that. Can you tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count clicks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var clicks = 0;
        $("#more").click(function (e) {
            if(clicks >= 10) {
              e.preventDefault();
              return false;
            }
            $("#clone").clone().appendTo("#main_wrap");
            clicks += 1;
        });
    });
```

To store clicks in hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="clicks" id="clicks">
```

Modify the jquery...

```
...
clicks += 1;
$('#clicks').val(clicks);
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks good. But I have another question, what about how can I POST the number of clicks value to another page too? I think I have to use it in loop for query.

Comment: Add a hidden input and update the value of it every time you record a click.

Comment: Like this?

     <input type='hidden' id = 'counter' name='counter' value='<?=$clicks?>'>

Comment: No no, check my edit. Php is server side. <input type="hidden" id="counter" name="counter"> Then you modify its value $('#counter').val(clicks)